# Disable activity slide-in animation when launching new activity?

Tags: android

I have an activity which launches another activity, via a button click. By default, on newer OS versions of android, the OS will animate the new activity sliding in from right to left.

Is there a way to disable this animation? I just want the new activity to appear without any sort of animation.

Answer (score 213):

The `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION` flag works fine for disabling the animation when starting activities.

To disable the similar animation that is triggered when calling `finish()` on an Activity, i.e the animation slides from right to left instead, you can call `overridePendingTransition(0, 0)` after calling `finish()` and the next animation will be excluded.

This also works on the in-animation if you call `overridePendingTransition(0, 0)` after calling `startActivity(...)`.

Comment: Note that `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION` and `overridePendingTransition` are both API Level 5+ only.

Comment: This does not help when going back from an activity on the Back key press.

Comment: You are the best. overridePendingTransition(0, 0) -> is godlike. It only overrides the finish() animation, but not the animation that is triggered when resuming the previous activity.

Comment: I dislike this answer because it does not cover transitions caused by pressing the 'back' softkeys. OP asks how to 'disable' the animation, not 'selectively tell the app to not play it'

Comment: If you want to disable or override the "back" animation as well, override the finish() method in your activity and put that call in there along with a call to super.finish(). Problem solved.

Comment: NOTE: you must call `overridePendingTransition(0,0)` *AFTER* `startActivity` or `finish` or whatever is doing the Activity change (in my case, `navigateUpTo()`).  Order really matters here.

Answer (score 196):

**Disclaimer**: 10+ years old answer. Please refer to the latest available documentation as believe it or not things do change.

IMHO [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9312957/304270) answer here solve issue in the most elegant way..

Developer should create a **style**,

```
<style name="noAnimTheme" parent="android:Theme">
  <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```

then **in manifest set it as theme** for activity or whole application.

```
<activity android:name=".ui.ArticlesActivity" android:theme="@style/noAnimTheme">
</activity>
```

Voila! Nice and easy..

*P.S. [credits to original author please](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9312957/304270)*

Comment: It doesn't work for Back, and it changes the look of title bar (it makes it small)...

Comment: are u sure u didn't add some other properties in style, cause for nobody else has reported this "effect" u mention..

Comment: Just for reference, this may cause a problem in a view hierarchy where you need to requestWindowFeature().

Comment: would be nice if u elaborate a bit, so we avoid posible problems

Comment: @Marek I guess your problem is not changing the parent="android:Theme" correctly.

You should change it with the theme you want use, basically this code just disables the specific animation in a theme.

for example use "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" instead of "android:Theme", and you'll get what I mean.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Not working when the parent is @style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog

Comment: Like Mattias said, to disable the finish transition call
`overridePendingTransition(0, 0)` before `finish()`

Comment: Like most android developers, I'm afraid of styles and themes.  I have too many burn scars from playing with these hot items.

Comment: @Tigerrrrr if you are not sure maybe is better to read official newest documentation instead of looking for a quick fix in a 11y old stackoverflow comment ;)

Comment: @Ewoks An 11y answer, that was updated only 3y ago, on a platform designed for answers with longevity... also, my comment was for anyone from the future trying to do this on <application> - longevity.

Comment: Not sure who promised you longevity, but seriously, take a look at official documentation, a lot changed in Android, pay attention to your target Android version (you didn't write anything about it) and it will be more accurate than first stackoverflow answer you stumbled upon

Answer (score 44):

Apply

```
startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class));
```

then

```
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

This will stop the animation.

Answer (score 33):

In my opinion the best answer is to use `"overridePendingTransition(0, 0);"`

to avoid seeing animation when you want to `Intent` to an `Activity` use:

```
this.startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), newactivity.class));
this.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

and to not see the animation when you press back button Override `onPause` method in your `newactivity`

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Just specify `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION` flag when starting

Answer (score 17):

This works for me when disabling finish Activity animation.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: This solution helps for case Intent(context, MyActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        startActivity(intent)

Answer (score 10):

I'm on 4.4.2, and **calling overridePendingTransition(0, 0) in the launching activity's onCreate() will disable the starting animation** (calling overridePendingTransition(0, 0) immediately after startActivity() did NOT work).  As noted in another answer, calling overridePendingTransition(0, 0) after finish() disables the closing animation.

Btw, I found that setting the style with "android:windowAnimationStyle">@null (another answer mentioned here) caused a crash when my launching activity tried to set the action bar title.  Debugging further, I discovered that somehow this causes window.hasFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR) to fail in the Activity's initActionBar().

Comment: what about onresume? single top activities and all that.

Answer (score 9):

FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION may work, but wasn't doing the trick for me when combined with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK and FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. I'm apparently seeing the animation for creating a new task with a fresh activity stack as I navigate laterally to my other top-level views.

What did work here was calling "overridePendingTransition(0, 0);" either immediately after my startActivity() call or the onPause(). Both ways worked, but doing it after startActivity() gives me a little more control over when I want animations and when I don't.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem of getting a black screen appear on sliding transition from one activity to another using `overridependingtransition`. and I followed the way below and it worked

1) created a `noanim.xml` in anim folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```

and used

```
overridePendingTransition(R.drawable.lefttorightanim, R.anim.noanim);
```

The first parameter as my original animation and second parameter which is the exit animation as my dummy animation

Comment: Why would you create such noanim file? Documentation says if looking for no animation just pass 0 as int like this: overridePendingTransition(R.drawable.lefttorightanim, 0);

Answer (score 3):

In order to avoid the black background when starting an activity already in the stack, I added 
`overridePendingTransition(0,0)` in `onStart()`:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
    super.onStart();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

To clear things up:
`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION` (or `android:windowAnimationStyle = @null` in the theme) work perfectly fine for both, enter and exit.
The problem is, that the enter animation checks if the animation is enabled in the one activity and the exit animation checks it for the other one. So make sure to disable it in both activities.