# Android -- is there anything wrong with doing the user interface almost entirely in OpenGL?

Tags: android, user-interface, graphics, opengl-es

What considerations should one be mindful of when constructing a GLSurfaceView-centric UI?
This is for a game and the bulk of the UI will be an intro screen (start, options, about, exit) and a level selector screen. I've put a lot of time into the rendering/animation for the game using OpenGL, and I'm no graphic artist, so taking the OGL UI route seems to make sense to me. But I'm an Android novice and need some outside input. Thanks for reading.

Comment: I have seen it done that way on other games and I have not noticed any real flaws to it. I would say if that is what you are familiar with then go for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the ease from which one activity can start another, I would say it is worthwhile to abstract your options and level selection from the game itself. If you're unfamiliar with starting activities and/or passing information between activities, there are plently of good tutorials and examples to help. You could try the ubiquitous Notepad tutorial if you haven't already ( http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html ).

The advantages of this method would be to leave your OpenGL/game Activity less cluttered, and that you would be able to use tried-and-true Android UI elements instead of building your own from scratch.

Comment: Here's a Q: If activity A's content view is GLSurfaceView A, and the activity is switched to activity B, whose view is also GLSurfaceView A, will there be any flickering?

Comment: Never tried that, myself, but perhaps if one used FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286315/disable-activity-slide-in-animation-when-launching-new-activity

Comment: However, the notion of a single instance of GLSurfaceView being the content of two different Activities is setting off warnings in my head...if you need the GLSurfaceView to be present in all your Activities, it may turn out to be better to use 1, as you originally planned. Can you perhaps describe how you're hoping to set up your game's start/options/select level menus? Like, what would the user see upon launching the app, and how would he navigate the menus and start the game, etc.

Comment: Splash screen fades to title/start menu w/ text fields. When user touches a text field the viewport slides over to a new set if information (eg options or about it). So the entire intro/title/options/about/levelselect is contained in one surfaceview on one larger-than-screen-size area. After selecting a level the app would switch to a new activity.

Comment: Ok, cool. In that case, I would say two Activities would be appropriate: one for your scrolling menu system, and then one for the game itself. Sounds like you're making your own UI components, but at least this way you would have separation of concerns, and wouldn't need to pass a GLSurfaceView between Activities.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with that, especially for a game. The only problem is that you will have to do *everything* yourself. Most games seem to be doing this.