# How can I avoid that my permanently visible menu slides out with the rest of the layout when switching between activities?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a menu that is always visible, and the same for all activities. Is it possible to avoid that the menu slides out along with the rest of the layout when launching a new activity? You can compare it to the way the tabwidget works, where the tabs remain in place while the rest of the layout switches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of ways come to mind.

1. If you want to keep using activities, you could fake it by [disabling their sliding animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286315/disable-activity-slide-in-animation-when-launching-new-activity). You would then have to manually do animations for the parts of the UI you want to slide in/out. I'm not sure how smooth this might look when going from one activity to the other.
2. Use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) and animate in/out the parts of the UI that are changing.

I would go the fragment route.

Comment: This is the best answer for me, primarily because I'm implementing a specific design, and the designer chose not to use the tab layout. I'm disabling the sliding animations, which don't happen in the tab layout either by the way. Both the answers from @Pompe de velo and @Jason Hanley are correct and solve my problem though

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to avoid that the menu slides out along with the rest of the layout when launching a new activity?

No, it's not possible. Everything within the current `Activity` are about to close/hide/animate out when you are starting a new `Activity`.

Consider the use of a [`Tab Layout`](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html).

Answer (score 0):

for reference sake:

if you use FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT, the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION will only work the first time the activity is created. Going to the activity back, will skip the onCreate where certainly the overridePendingTransition() method is called.

You should add "overridePendingTransition(0,0)" in your onResume and the animation will disappear for good.

```
public void launchSecondActivity(){
    Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    //this flag will lead to problem the second time
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT); 
    startActivity(i);
}

//add this to your activities to fix it
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
}
```