# Disable Transition Animation Between Activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am calling an Activity B  from Activity A, which contains a Video View using the following code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

I am using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION` to avoid transition animation while new activity is being called.  But its not working for me and a black screen is coming while the transition. Is there any way to avoid this transition animation and black screen, so that the user will not come to know that the video view is being called in a new screen?

Comment: Try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972295/switching-activities-without-animation

Or this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286315/disable-activity-slide-in-animation-when-launching-new-activity

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you want to do it for all activities then do it in this way:

[switching activities without animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972295/switching-activities-without-animation)

Just assign style with no animation to each activity in manifest.

Or through code do it in this way:

[Disable activity slide-in animation when launching new activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286315/disable-activity-slide-in-animation-when-launching-new-activity)

Answer (score 72):

Try calling:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
overridePendingTransition(0,0); //0 for no animation
```

Comment: This worked for me also thanks! Quick question, why are you using startActivityForResult() instead of just startActivity()? I get the same desired result (no animation) with both?

Comment: @EvanM You don't have to use startActivityForResult(). You'd only use it if you wanted to get a "result" back from the next Activity.

Comment: just using `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);` worked for me.

Comment: on marshmallow don't work without ``overridePendingTransition``

Comment: @Micro sorry but only the original answer worked! Seems `overridePendingTransition` is a must.

Answer (score 0):

Took me quite some time to figure it out...

to support overriding transition when coming back from another Activity:

use `overridePendingTransition` in your Activity `onResume`.

```
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        // disable transition when coming back from an activity
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
    }
```