# Stable Tab Bar on every Activity Transitions

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an app and I have tab bars on top and bottom of the screen.
These tab bars are included with include tag for every layouts so they will appear every time.But while a new activity is starting , my tab bars also move because of transition anim between activities.I want them stable.How can I do that.Thanks for advices..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first probably have to disable the default animation for the activity. This should help: [Disable activity slide-in animation when launching new activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286315/disable-activity-slide-in-animation-when-launching-new-activity)

And then apply the animation you want to the (non-tab)view, in the onCreate() of the launched activity, using a view animation. This could be a good start: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html

Comment: Thank you @lxx . Disabling animation with overridePendingTransition(0, 0) is totally enough for me.It works...