# How to disable the animation of an Activity when calling moveTaskToBack()?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

I have been trying to disable the animation of my activity when calling `moveTaskToBack()`. I am testing on my Nexus 7 on Marshmallow, and no matter what I do, the "sliding down" animation is still there.

Things that I have tried:

- Calling `overridePendingTransition(0, 0);` after `moveTaskToBack()`
- Calling `overridePendingTransition(0, 0);` in `onDestroy()` and `onPause()`
- Calling `getWindow().setWindowAnimations(0);` in the above places
- Create a custom style for the activity with the following:

.

```
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@null</item>
<item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@null</item>
<item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@null</item>
<item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@null</item>
<item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@null</item>
```

None of the above and their combination work. I am out of idea. Can someone help me out please?

Comment: Try this:
startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class));
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

OR

try this link:
[link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972295/switching-activities-without-animation/9312957#9312957)
[link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286315/disable-activity-slide-in-animation-when-launching-new-activity)

Comment: I tried all of that, as you can see in my question

Comment: @Chin : were you able to find a solution for this? I am currently stuck on the same problem.

Comment: @Swayam I never found a solution to this, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with this, this can help

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally need this too.
I'm good with the result of following settings

```
<style name="noAnimation">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@null</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@null</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@null</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@null</item>
    <item name="android:taskOpenEnterAnimation">@null</item>
    <item name="android:taskOpenExitAnimation">@null</item>
    <item name="android:taskCloseEnterAnimation">@null</item>
    <item name="android:taskCloseExitAnimation">@null</item>
    <item name="android:taskToFrontEnterAnimation">@null</item>
    <item name="android:taskToFrontExitAnimation">@null</item>
    <item name="android:taskToBackEnterAnimation">@null</item>
    <item name="android:taskToBackExitAnimation">@null</item>
</style>
```

// then overwrite theme with style above.

```
<style name="Theme.noAnimation" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/noAnimation</item>
</style>
```

Hope this could help others who need this :)