# Android App Memory Leak - android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I am developing my first Android App and it has memory leak. I have already used tools like MAT but I still can't find out where does the leak come from.

A bit of the context and situation: there are many Activities in my app. When I repeatedly go from Activity A to Activity B and then back to Activity A again, the memory used will keep increasing. This happen for all the Activities which I have tried.

By MAT leak suspect analysis (see the first image link), there are huge amount of "android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord" which I have no idea what it is.

I am very new to programming, and I have studied this problem for days, read dozens of Stack Overflow posts and still have no idea where the leak comes from.

Here are a few screen caps of MAT analysis results:

[MAT leak suspect report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUe7D.png)

[Comparison of MAT Histogram of 2 different time points (after filtering out objects which are not coded by me)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyJxi.png)

Almost all of the activities share some fragments

- DayTimeFragment (Shared by all activities)
- StatusBarFragment (Shared by all activities)
- BackButtonFragment (Shared by some activities)
- ButtonFragment (Shared by some activities)

Comment: I found LeakCanary (https://github.com/square/leakcanary) much easier to use and more precise in its results.

Answer (score 2):

i didnt go through your data so i cant say for certain, but your error messages are similar to these reports:

- [`AOSP:170469`](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=170469)
- [`LeakCanary:167`](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/167)
- [`LeakCanary:185`](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/185)

i was getting LeakCanary log messages of leaks stemming from `android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord` too and resolved it by disabling Transitions between all my activities as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286315/disable-activity-slide-in-animation-when-launching-new-activity).

i dont know if there are other workarounds nor which versions this particular workaround is compatible with but i used `overridePendingTransition(0, 0);` immediately after any invocations of `startActivity` (static utility method) and again on every activity's `onPause` (in a base-class).