# Android crash in setContentView

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, setcontentview

Any idea about crash below - only happening in one particular device MI 4 on setContentView. The resource which was not found is an android resource. Also, We do not have any animation in our code but looks like it's performed by android.

I tried searching for *linear_out_slow_in* in source and generated files but only found in one generated file - mockable-android-25.jar

**Please note that, app is working fine on over 20 test devices we having and 435 other customer devices. This issue is particularly with MI 4 device.**

```
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2661)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2722)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6114)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:764)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/interpolator/linear_out_slow_in.xml from xml type anim resource ID #0x10c000e

at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadXmlResourceParser(ResourcesImpl.java:1018)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2125)
at android.content.res.Resources.getAnimation(Resources.java:1153)
at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(AnimationUtils.java:275)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.<init>(DecorView.java:235)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2342)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2680)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2051)
at android.support.v7.app.n.x(SourceFile:3379)
at android.support.v7.app.n.b(SourceFile:289)
at android.support.v7.app.f.setContentView(SourceFile:140)
at com.qualto.android.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:127)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6736)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2614)
```

Following is view xml causing crash

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include layout="@layout/include_list_viewpager"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

ext {
    PUBLISH_VERSION = '1.0.1'
    VERSION_CODE = 10
    SUPPORTLIB_VER = '25.3.1'
    PLAYSERVICE_VER = '10.2.0'
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
       //removed
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.qualto.android"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode project.VERSION_CODE
        versionName project.PUBLISH_VERSION
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude '.readme'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            //buildConfigField "boolean", "DEBUG", "true"
            //minifyEnabled true
            //shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/aidl']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${project.SUPPORTLIB_VER}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${project.SUPPORTLIB_VER}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${project.SUPPORTLIB_VER}"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${project.SUPPORTLIB_VER}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:${project.SUPPORTLIB_VER}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${project.SUPPORTLIB_VER}"

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:${project.PLAYSERVICE_VER}"
}
```

Comment: both are pretty much latest gradle 2.3.2, support library 5.2.0

Comment: what´s your min target?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs it's 14

Comment: ok, I think it´s better to post your gradle file...

Comment: I am not sure if it the right way to set the reference in brackets: `{project.SUPPORTLIB_VER}"` . I just know it without it and without `project.`: `"com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORTLIB_VER"` . But maybe it´s just another way to do that I don´t know...

Comment: **Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/interpolator/linear_out_slow_in.xml from xml type anim** - Logcat doesn't lie - you are referencing a resource (/linear_out_slow_in) that your project doesn't contain.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs that's not an issue. The code is working on 20 other test devices we have, this issue is only with specific device MI 4.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs btw on a side note, $SUPPORTLIB_VER is shorter, thanks for the tip.

Comment: maybe you should report that to XIAOMI, it seems to be a bug here.

Comment: true. looks like, but just wondering is there something we can do to avoid it, especially since we are not calling any animation functions.

Comment: mmm very strange. I guess you are refering any theme/style that puts that animation for default to your activities...and then it crashs because of that bug..

Comment: Our AppTheme is Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar. There is no reference to animation in our own styles.xml

Comment: yes I know. But every device has it´s default transitions for switching screens. Does this crash happen directly on start the app or somewhere between the use?

Comment: there are several ways to disable an animation between activities...see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286315/disable-activity-slide-in-animation-when-launching-new-activity. I think you should give it a try...

Comment: What API is the device that's failing?  I would guess that device is having trouble with the support-v4 library you are using.  Could you try using an older (or newer) library?  [Support Library Revisions](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html).  Also, just FYI,
 [Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html)