# Oreo: disable Activity transition animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-8.0-oreo

I need to disable Activity transition animation for all the screens in my application. Previous solution worked fine for all Android version:

```
<style name="base_theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```

... but for Android 8 "Oreo" it cause black screen blinking for every transition (forward or back move). I.e. there is still no any animation, but very annoying blinking take place (90% chance, ~20-30 milliseconds, the whole screen).

According to my "research":

- it does not depends on activity content and reproduced with empty activities
- there is no any background work which could slow down the transition process
- Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION blinks as well
- overridePendingTransition(0,0) doesn't work too

**The only solution I could find:**

Define an empty transition animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set />
```

and apply it to every activity in the application (onCreate & finish)

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_activity_none, R.anim.animation_activity_none);
```

**Question:**

Is it some kind of new restrictions for Oreo (i.e. feature), or platform bug, or maybe the application issue?
Are there any other solutions?

**[UPDATE]**

One more finding. Make sure you call Activity finish() and overridePendingTransition() pair on the main thread! Otherwise thread race happens and overridePendingTransition not applied sometimes.

**[UPDATE]**

Google has confirmed it's a bug in Android 8.0, presumably fixed in 8.1.
So the "empty animation" fix is for years, until minSdkVersion == 27.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11079475/2949834 Did you try changing parent as parent="android:Theme"?

Comment: @KimKevin yes, it blinks anyway. So it doesn't mater Activity or AppCompatActivity is used.

Comment: @SergeyKrivenkov thank you so much for this. I can see you did a lot of painstaking work to dig into this and explore reduced test cases, so your solution saved me a ton of time going down the same path. Did you report this in the Android issue tracker?

Comment: @hustoj2 submitted a bug report https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67728861

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and I managed to solve it, the idea is to play nothing, please see the xml below:

Values folder

```
<style name="yourTheme">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/ThemeApp.Animation.Activity.Replace</item>
```

```
<style name="ThemeApp.Animation.Activity.Replace">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/replace_anim</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/replace_anim</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/replace_anim</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/replace_anim</item>
    <item name="android:taskOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/replace_anim</item>
    <item name="android:taskOpenExitAnimation">@anim/replace_anim</item>
```

Anim folder: replace_anim.xml

```
<set/>
```

Comment: you described the same solution as mentioned in the Question part above - play empty animation. But the question: why it happens?

Comment: Please check the issue link. Android confirmed it was a bug in O which is apparently fixed already. I haven't confirmed it yet but they attached a video