# Android MapsActivity - onclick reload activity

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a google map in MapsActivity with 3 clickable buttons. Each button shows different markers on the map.

This is achieved via:

```
 public void AllMap(View v) //first button
{
    SharedPreferences mypref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditr = mypref.edit();
    prefsEditr.putInt("mapselect", 1);
    prefsEditr.apply();

    finish();
    Button button = findViewById(R.id.allmap);
    button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( 0, R.drawable.allmapon, 0, 0);
    button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff5722"));
    startActivity(getIntent());
}
```

And then on Map setup I read the SharedPreferences and according to the selected option I add Markers on the map.

This is working fine, but after I click, the whole activity reloads but it seems like a right to left slide animation. So the new reloaded activity comes from right side of device.

I have no animations or something like that set, but seems this is default behavior for all my activities on my device. However it seems not very good in MapsActivity. Is there a way to refresh the MapsActivity without restarting it - so just the markers will change?

What should I call instead of `finish(); startActivity(getIntent());` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What should I call instead of finish(); startActivity(getIntent()); to refresh map?

You can clear all the existing marker by invoking `mMap.clear()` and add the markers again according to new shared preference values.

Or

You can keep the references of your marker in arralist or something so that you can change their locations in map

Comment: not a bad idea, but I think I've found the easiest solution using  finish();
        overridePendingTransition( 0, 0);
        startActivity(getIntent());
        overridePendingTransition( 0, 0);  This removes the right to left animation and the map just reloads with new markers. Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @wotan that's just remove the animation of activity recreation and it will take time and resources to reload everything (activity creation, object creation like preference etc ), loading map so at some point you have to improve the efficiency (unless it's a hobby project or something :P), [other option to kill animation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2286315/4936904), glad to help

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining. In that case, I tried your suggestion with mMap.clear(); and then i call SetupMap();. I am very surprised as this is working very quick! The markers are replaced immediately and without restarting the whole activity. Thank you very much @Pavneet_Singh for helping me. You are a good man!

Comment: thank you,I am glad that I could help, just one heads up, make sure we are not calling map.async etc because we already has the map setup, just need to just add markers again, happy coding!