# Activity exiting and entering animation problem

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I am facing problem in my app. Without mentioning any animation or transition in the code I am getting animation on activity Enter and exit and they are both the same type of animation Slide in left.

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/googlesansregular</item>
</style>
```

Comment: can you please share your code.

Comment: It could be your device. Do you see this animation in other applications to?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286315/disable-activity-slide-in-animation-when-launching-new-activity/15872697) out!

Comment: i install application in other devices. but same problem.