# Why can't I disable the animation for changing activities when using FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

In my game when the user decides to switch screens from let's say the Messages screen to the Profile screen, I want to make sure the user can switch screens and be able to maintain previous activity.

So I have this bit of code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Profile.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivityIfNeeded(intent, 0);
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

It works, except it only disables the animation when switching from screens for the first time, after that it doesn't work. It plays the animation and I don't want that.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to move from one to another that's it with no animation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable activity slide-in animation when launching new activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286315/disable-activity-slide-in-animation-when-launching-new-activity)

Comment: @RumitPatel I've already looked at the responses to that question and none of them solves my problem.

Comment: I'm confused. You are using `startActivityIfNeeded()`. This is a variant of `startActivityForResult()`. When you launch an `Activity` and expect it to return a result, the `Activity` that you launched needs to call `finish()` in order for the result to be returned to the calling `Activity`. In this case, there will never be an existing instance of `Profile`, because all previously used instances would have finished. Please edit your post and explain more of your architecture and how this is supposed to work. Also include your manifest in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can just disable the animation as @DKV suggested.

Instead of this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Profile.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivityIfNeeded(intent, 0);
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);  // remove this line
```

Try using this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Profile.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivityIfNeeded(intent, 0);
```

Note that

> addFlags

not

> setFlags

Comment: The animation still runs. The animation doesn't run only when switching screens for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9312957/304270) answer.

Create a style with no animation specified:
`<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>`

And then use it as the theme for that activity in the manifest.