# Android splash screen jump java

Tags: java, android, xml, splash-screen

I wanted to implement a splash screen but in a correct way - no superficial delay, only showing it while the app is doing some real work. So I googled a lot and found following solution: I apply theme to SplashActivity, procced with the logic and open next activity. The problem is that splash screen jumps a little bit. Tried different options - fullscreen, no action bar for splash, no action bar for splash and following activity, android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds true\false and several others. If I set delay for 115-150 millisecs then 9 cases out of 10 there is no jump. The question is how to get rid of the jump and keep splash screen lean.

SplashActivity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends CheckForInternetActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        routeActivity();
    }
```

AndroidManifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name="ru.awac.CBoRrates.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

styles.xml:

```
 <style name="AppTheme.SplashScreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

splash_screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:opacity="opaque">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:src="@drawable/awac_presents_transparent_1" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

awac_presents_transparent_1 is just a png

[Youtube video of the jump](https://youtu.be/D7A9UcmBECk)

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by jumping?

Comment: Kinda like quick flinch with logo going up and down. Can post a video later.

Comment: @SanjidChowdhury, added video to the question. Please find it in the bottom.

Comment: I think this is due to the activity having an animation when it starts. Please refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286315/disable-activity-slide-in-animation-when-launching-new-activity to disable the activity transition animation and see if it helps

Comment: @SanjidChowdhury, thanks I'm gonna try it and report on results.

Comment: @SanjidChowdhury yay! It worked thanks a lot! I ended up adding 
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item> to AppTheme.SplashScreen. Wanna add an answer so I could upvote it?